# Does Netbeans support non-English languages?

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, filenames, mojibake

#### Does Netbeans really support unicode (UTF-8), or better, it does really support non-English languages?

I've played a bit with java and Netbeans, but I got some issues. I could think its a problem with java, but I don't think so.

1. I needed to convert a file from some encoding to UTF-8, I thought that it was very trivial to do because the JEdit (a simple text editor) and lots of simple text editors supports it, by default. Sadly, impressed, I found that its not possible with Netbeans without some sort of plugin. See something like in [this bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114123). Because of the surprise I gave up and then got back to JEdit.
2. After few days, lets give another try, but now, got similar problem to this [other bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=118232), but instead, with Portuguese language (diacritic things don't work). The `ç` was being replaced by `_` in the jar filename. Had to fix manually the filename in the project properties. Ok, that pass.
3. Again the problem described in 2), but now the term known [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is what I see navigating through the filenames inside the jar file, the `çã` was being replaced by `Ã§Ã£`, in the MANIFEST.MF file.

They didn't say that all the project should be in UTF-8? So why MANIFEST.MF made by
"them" is not?

---

### Environment

- Netbeans: 7.3

  JDK: 7 update 17

  OS: Windows 7

  Locale: Português (Brasil)

---

### Update

Same problem with the generated README.TXT under the dist/ folder. But now in netbeans its displayed as little squares.

I've checked the encoding specified in the project and at least the sources seems to be in UTF-8. In my netbeans its found in project properties > "Códigos-fonte" and then "Codificação" (encoding).

---

### Solutions

#### Translation to US-English

- Translate everything that touches the Java development environment to US English.
- Start teaching myself English, and perhaps, to other too.

#### Use a bat file to build the application

Note: I've tested on my environment and it works.

You can edit your files with Netbeans and just don't build anything with it, just edit the source files.

Here is a very simple example, so you can start with (remember to save in UTF-8):

**C:\in your project folder\builder.bat**

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
title Building the application
set path=%path%;c:\java\jdk\bin
set app=(UTF-8 application name)
echo.
echo # Cleaning
del %app%.class %app%.jar
echo.
echo # Compiling...
javac -Xlint:deprecation -g -encoding UTF-8 %app%.java
echo.
echo # Packaging...
jar cvfm %app%.jar %app%.manifest %app%.class
echo.
echo # Executing...
java %app%
```

---

**Conclusions**

It is a so nice IDE, with so many features, why this?

Unicode is not new, even in the Windows...

I really do understand the difficulties of maintaining one project in one language, I can think what could be it in multiple languages! So, sorry for the developers that reads it, I'm not criticizing it negatively, I do really want known if this IDE (or even the whole Java development environment) is meant to be used within other languages beyond the English.

### See also

For a simple text editor (you'll find JEdit there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182071/lightweight-java-ide .

Comment: *the `çã` was being replaced by `Ã§Ã£`* => How did you check that? Are you sure the editor you used was decoding UTF-8?

Comment: In netbeans (inside the project) double clicking the MANIFEST.MF (dist/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) I could see the "Main-Class:" field with wrong characters being displayed. And sure, this leads to main class not found error.

Comment: What is the solution here? any plugins for netbeans? It is unable to recognize 'ã€€' and throws a 'unclosed character literal' exception.